# Amazon web services - basic workflow

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a PHP/MySQL application test-deployed on a server, with a domain name that I own. In order for this to be a real world scalable product, I decided to use Amazon Web Services. However, I'm new to using cloud services (this is my first), and since the past 2 days, after going through tutorials and "how to start" guides given on Amazon, I've still been unable to grasp "what exactly should I do, so that I can use my present domain name *and* use Amazon's services?"
 My users should be able to access my product using, let's say `www.xyz.com` which is the name I own. My PHP code gets some data from client, which it then stores in a SQL DB. This is the existing, working set up.

Now, how do I get my PHP code, to use Amazon Web Servics and store it in a database that Amazon provides? My product's DB will be continuously growing, and I will pay for whatever is used. Also, if I decide to use the PHP services from Amazon too, does Amazon host my code? In that case, what will be the domain name?

To summarize, my biggest concern is the domain name I've bought, and I've seen no documentation on how to go forward in such a case.

This is the only part I have been unable to figure out, rest was clear from the documentation..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: With EC2, you have to set everything up yourself. To get your domain name to work, get a static IP and configure your CNAME records (or ALIAS, I don't remember off the top of my head) through your domain name registrar and have them point to the EC2 IP. If you don't know how to manage a server, just use Heroku or any of the other PaaS services.

Comment: I'll just add, that while you can use any DNS host provider, when working with any of the AWS services, having you DNS managed by AWS's Route 53 makes many things a lot easier and quicker to do. For example, if route 53 mananges your DNS, you can validate a domain for use with SES with a couple of clicks, if you host your DNS elsewhere, you need to manually cut and paste records into DNS.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan Yes, I've configured my account at the previous service provider to use the AWS's Route 53.

Comment: @Blender Can you elaborate more on that if possible? I can manage a server, if given access to. What does Heroku and PaaS services offer different?

Comment: @sanjeevmk: You just use `heroku commit -m "message" && heroku push master` and your code is uploaded to Heroku via Git and deployed automatically. You don't need to do anything. The problem with it is that it's expensive once you need to break out of the free tier usage plan.

Comment: @Blender Thanks. What is the corresponding process for AWS, any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Web Services (AWS) is a cloud platform composed of multiple services that jointly enable you to host infrastructure and applications on it. It's not a single offering that magically does everything for you. In order to achieve your goal you will want to do the following:

1. Use Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) to spin up servers that host your PHP application. They will handle the incoming traffic for you. Have a look at [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html) to get started.
2. In order to store data you will want to use some sort of database. AWS offers various database types. Since you are looking for a SQL-type database, you will want to use [RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html). This service allows you to provision a functional database and relieves you of certain administrative tasks.
3. In order to use your current domain, you will have to transfer its registration to AWS Route53. Just Google 'Route53 domain transfer' and the documentation will show you how to do it.

There are many whitepapers available that show architectural patterns across the AWS cloud. I suggest you read them so you can get a better understanding of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

To get started quickly I recommend using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for your purposes:

> Amazon Web Services (AWS) comprises dozens of services, each of which
>   exposes an area of functionality. While the variety of services offers
>   flexibility for how you want to manage your AWS infrastructure, it can
>   be challenging to figure out which services to use and how to
>   provision them.
>
> With Elastic Beanstalk, you can quickly deploy and manage applications
>   in the AWS Cloud without worrying about the infrastructure that runs
>   those applications. AWS Elastic Beanstalk reduces management
>   complexity without restricting choice or control. You simply upload
>   your application, and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the
>   details of capacity provisioning, load balancing, scaling, and
>   application health monitoring.

Learn more about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)

regarding the domain, you could [transfer it to route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html)

OR

[route your domain traffic by using route53 name servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html)